# I want to add constraint using alter command in psql

Tags: psql, alter

I have created a table.

But I need to add a constraint for price that price must be greater than 10.

How it can be done using alter command....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `check` command.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  testCol INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE test
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_value CHECK (testCol > 10);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e56da6)